# Reason to convey to new employer for rejecting already accepted offer

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, recruitment

I'm a software professional. I got an offer in a company with a good package. But my current employer offered me an opportunity onsite which I feel is more valuable compared to the package offered by the new company.

How can I convey that my current employer has offered me an onsite position and I'm rejecting the new offer?

I do not want to leave a bad impression with the new company or lose future opportunities with them.

Comment: Why did you want to leave in the first place? What prompted you to start looking at other jobs? Be very careful unless the *only* reasons have all been dealt with satisfactorily by the counter-offer. Most people who accept counter-offers don't stay that long in any case, and your current company will know this; you may be already marked down as "disloyal" or "mercenary".

Comment: I apologize but I have accepted another position with my current employer.  You will most likely lose future opportunities with them.

Comment: You already accepted the previous offer. By reneging on that acceptance you can consider this bridge burned. The reason won't matter. They're very unlikely to want to take a second chance on someone who has been insincere and wasted their time.

Answer (score 7):

You should really have discussed a potential counter-offer from your current employer *before* accepting the new offer. Give them a deadline if necessary. "I need to accept or reject the offer from the potential new employer by Friday. Please think about whether you can and want to give me an attractive counter-offer in writing by that time."

Accepting an offer from a new employer and *then* deciding to go with the counter-offer is unprofessional, there is no way around it, and you won't be able to sugarcoat it very much.

If you did immediately request a counter-offer from your current employer, but *they* were late about making it, the unprofessionalism lies with them. In this case, you can tell the alternative employer that the counter-offer was late in coming. (Without badmouthing your current employer.)

---

That said, just tell the new employer as soon as possible (they will need to restart their search) that you will unfortunately need to renege on your accepting their offer, since your current employer made a more attractive counter-offer. No need to go into details. Explain that you understand and regret that this is not a good situation. As I said, you *will* be burning bridges somewhat.

If you are a *really* strong candidate, your new employer might even make a counter-counter-offer, or you might even suggest something along these lines. However, initiating negotiations like this after accepting an offer and then reneging on it might backfire badly. Tread carefully here.

Answer (score -2):

First off I must disagree with some of the other answers here that doing so is unprofessional. I have been in this situation and the company I eventually turned down understood what I had done and why. There were no hard feelings and they even left me with an open offer for the future if I ever decided to reapply.

There are basically 2 ways you can go about this.

You have already accepted an offer from company A and you now have a better offer from company B (from a later date than your acceptance). I would go back to company A and tell them you have another more appealing offer (and potentially more lucrative) from company B and kindly ask if they can match or exceed the offer that company B has made. This may put you in the situation of company A making you an even better offer than you had.

Your other option with company A is to simply call the person that recruited you/hired you and explain that you have another offer that you will be going with.

I work in the software world and these things happen all the time, and generally much faster than in other fields as software jobs come and go very quickly. Don't be ashamed to take the better offer here. In the end of the day you are responsible for your carer and you need to make the decisions that are right for you.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry to hear that my colleague, I don't think you should accept the purpose first. You probably should first discuss the opportunity and taking in consideration if your current employer would interest about keeping you in the company.

Now, you already has a bad image with new employer, due the commitment factor. You already commit with accepting the offer. I don't think you should decline or regret an already accept offer it won't be much professional from you. Just say to your current employer you must leave and decline the counter offer.

If you accept the new offer so I think new one is good enough for you! Don't make 
yourself an auction.